# Java8 streams: generic logger method in stream

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I want to create a method that prints out information within a stream. Please take a look at my existing logger method.
The method arguments have to be generic like in my example string & integer.
The method is supposed to return the original object, in my case string.
Can someone tell me what's wrong with my current method?

Thanks a lot in advance!

look at the logger-method

```java
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("A", "BC", "XYZ");

stream.map(t -> logger(t.length()))
   .map(t-> logger(t.substring(0, 2)))
   .collection(Collectors.toList());

public static <T> T logger(T t) {
    System.out.println(t);
    return t;
  }
```

ERROR: Cannot infer type argument(s) for  map(Function)

Comment: `logger(t.length())` will return integer so in your second map you will have Integers and you cannot call `substring` from Integer.

Comment: You're passing `t.length()` to your `logger` function, which is an `int`, so your `T` is `Integer`.

Comment: Side note : why method that should log something, also returns some value?

Comment: I want to use the same logger method for int (t.length) and string (t.substring(0,2)

Comment: @michalk because I need the object for the next map() method in stream

Comment: @michalk I assume he is trying to accomplish something like `peek(System.out::println)`, but with assurance it will run and also while specifying some `Function` of `T` instead of just `T`.

Comment: Why do you want to log any type?  Pretty much everything in Java can be trivially converted to a `String`.  e.g. Make `logger()` take a `String` and then call `logger(String.valueOf(t.length()))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why not use Stream#peek()?

This looks like an example of where you might want to use `.peek()` instead of a map. It's specifically built for printing out, and you don't need to worry about returning anything!

It might look more like:

```
stream.peek(it -> System.out.println(it.length))
    .peek(it -> System.out.println(it.substring(0, 2))
    // presumably other functions here before collecting...
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Take a look at the official documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-

### Back to the Original Question

To address your previous question, you probably want to update your function so that it takes a pure example of T, and a transform for T. You can update it to look like:

```
public static <T, R> T logger(T t, Function<T, R> transform) {
  R logLine = transform.apply(t);
  System.out.println(logLine);
  return t;
}
```

and your code will look like

```
stream.map(element -> logger(element, element::length)) // and so on
```

Comment: Note that `peek` is not guaranteed to execute for Java 9+ (without silly workarounds).

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible with my logger method too? Waht is it supposed to like like?

Comment: @Zircon that's a good call out, maybe verify that it will work.. @Toark I've added an example of what it might look like if you keep your existing method structure

Comment: @gar.stauffer exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Zircon, what do you mean "silly workarounds"? Is it about `count()` for sized streams?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I read somewhere that `peek` is guaranteed to occur if you make the size of the stream programatically non-final, for example by adding a `filter(e -> true)` after the `peek`. But that doesn't seem proper to me.

Comment: @Zircon, if it is indeed about the `count()`, then for cases where size is already known, no need to look at elements to count them, so it won't run any stages and won't `peek()`. It's in javadoc for `count` as well. However, if you need to look at all elements, you can just do a `forEach` and look at'em. It is also not required to `peek()` at all elements if terminalOperation is `findFirst` or `findAny`. What it more or less says is you shouldn't use `count` operation to count all elements, and you shouldn't rely on `peek` (intended for debugging in most cases) in conjunction with it.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov that makes sense, thanks for that info!

Answer (score 1):

The problem I face here is that the first map is return an integer, so you are trying to use `Integer.substring` which does not exists.

What I recommend in your case is to use `peek` instead of `map`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class InferType {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("A", "BC", "XYZ");

        stream.peek(t -> logger(t.length()))
                .peek(t-> logger(t.substring(0, 2)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static <T> void logger(T t) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on my end

```java
import java.util.stream.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("AX", "BC", "XYZ");


    stream.map(t -> logger(t))
      .map(t-> logger(t.substring(0, 1)))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    /* or this
    stream.map(t -> logger(t))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    */

  }

public static <T> T logger(T t) {
    System.out.println(t);
    return t;
  }
}
```

Have a look at what a stream() map() really does [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-map-java-examples/). But basically, it says

> Stream map(Function mapper) returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the > given function to the elements of this stream.

edit: @Ezequiel made a good point about `Integer.substring`

Comment: `stream.map(t -> logger(t.length)):` You're saying take the value `t` and call the method `logger` on it, but pass in its length (integer). When you do that `t` is now `t.length`. Now when you call `.map(t-> logger(t.substring(0, 1)))` you're saying oh yeah give me the previous value (now t.length, an integer) and get me the substring. But an integer has no substring. That's why the commented code still compiles: because there's no additional processing, you just collect it back.